# Creating a "div sandwich" with fixed-height bread slice divs and an expandable meat div

Tags: html, css

So I have a div sandwich: three divs on top of one another. The slices of bread are both fixed-height due to background images. The meat is a 1px tall vertical repeater image. I need a way to expand the meat when overflow content from the top breadslice hits the bottom of the bottom breadslice. I figured a wrapper would be necessary for the meat and the bottom bread, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Here's what I have thus far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #top {
            position:relative;
            height:100px;
            background-color:pink;
            width:460px;
            word-wrap:break-word;
        }
        #wrapper {
            position:relative;
        }
        #expand {
            min-height:100%;
            height:auto;
            background-color:#EEEFFF;
        }
        #bottom {
            height:100px;
            background-color:#EEEEEE;
        }
        div.clear{
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            clear:both;
            height:1px;
            overflow:hidden;
            border:solid orange;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="top">
        a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="expand"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a way to make top's content hit against the "clear" in the bottom wrapper and move the wrapper down.

Comment: +1 For the Title - Helped me out too. "Expandable Meat Div" =D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this the effect you're after?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #top {
            position:absolute;
            height:100px;
            background-color:pink;
            width:460px;
            top:0px;
        }
        #wrapper {
            position:relative;
        }
        #expand {
            position:absolute;
            top:100px; /*height of top div*/
            bottom:100px; /*height of bottom div*/
            width:100%;
            background-color:#cccFFF;
        }
        #bottom {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0px;
            height:100px;
            width:560px;
            background-color:#EEEEEE;
        }
        #text
        {
         position:relative;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="expand"></div>
      <div id="top"></div>
      <div id="bottom"></div>         
      <div id="text">
         a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The only other needed for this model to work is for the wrapper to have a min-height set to the breadslices' combined height. Good job everyone, I wouldn't have thought of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you’ve got content overflowing a fixed height element, then the overflowing content won’t affect the layout of other elements.

Could you move your content out of the top bread slice, and into the meat? That will make the expanding happen.

If the content needs to appear in front of the top bread slice background, then you could use `position: relative` and a negative bottom margin to achieve that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #breadtop,
        #breadbottom {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #977;
        }

        #breadtop {
            overflow: visible;
        }

        #meat {
            background-color: #fbd;
        }

        #content {
            position: relative;
            top: -100px;
            margin-bottom: -100px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="breadtop"></div>
    <div id="meat">
        <div id="content">
            a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
            a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
            a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="breadbottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I like this question because it’s quite tricky, and because it contains the phrase “expandable meat div”.

Comment: This is a legitimate approach, but the usage of margins messed with other items I have on the page. I opted to instead put the content in a sandwich wrapper outside of the sandwich flow, like in david's suggestion. Thanks for helping though, I'm glad you liked my meat div.

Answer (score 1):

(If you want example code I can come up with it, but It'll take me longer to answer)

What you may want to do is place your 3 slices in a div, and put your "top" content in the new div instead of the top slice. This way your new div's height will be determined by the content.

For the 3 slices, absolute position all of them. Put the top and bottom slices at the top and bottom of your new div using `top:0` and `bottom:0`, respectively. For the middle meat slice, don't give it a height, but instead make it's `top` and `bottom` declarations equal to the height of your top and bottom slices. This way, the top/bottom of the meat will always be held X pixels away from the top/bottom of your new div, where X is the top/bottom slice's height.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did in the code I posted. Works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

I allways follow this example: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/